# Machine learning unsupervised approach to extract pattern from text data using python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, text-classification, pattern-recognition

I would like to know that how to use unsupervised approach to exract pattern from the text data.

I have data set about the description of the product in the form of title,short and long description.My goal is to find the value of product attribute using the description available.The value which I am trying to find is present in the descripton in many varaitions.

```
Below are few examples of attribute which product has:

1. recomended minimum and maximum age for particular product.(get the values)

2. Is particular product is made from recycling or not ? (Yes or no).

3. Is remote control included for particular product ? (yes or no)
```

Currently I am using the regualar expression to get the values/find if its present in the data or not. But its very hard to find the values as I mentioned the values are present in many variations. I can't write all rules or more specific to say I can't generalize these patterns. If new varaitions come then my regex gets fail.

I was wondering is there any fairly intuitive way to automatically build these regex patterns with some sort of algorithm.

How do I use machine learning approach to build some intelligence model that can solve my problem.

Below is one example of the prodcut description.

```
Example:

UVM1067  Features   Quantity per Selling Unit: 1 Set  **Total Recycled Content: 30pct**  Product Keywords: Kleer-Fax, Inc., Indexes, 8 Color, 10 Color Binders  Sets per Pack: 1  Tab Style: 15-Tab  Color: Multicolor  Country of Manufacture: United States  Index Divider Style: Printed Numeric   Dimensions   Overall Height - Top to Bottom: 11''  Overall Width - Side to Side: 8.5''  Overall Product Weight: 0.3 lbs
```

You can see in above description of the product it mentioned that **total recycled** it means that product is made from recycled so I would like to predict the 'Y' as my output.

I can do this by searching word or regex but i want to build some intelligent/automatic model/way to achive this.

Thanks,

Niranjan

Comment: If anything, this is a *supervised* machine learning problem. Pattern-recognition per definitionem requires you to specify a pattern to match.

Comment: yes I have pattern means I know what to extact but it appearing in many vaariations in text.  That's why I can not automate it . I need to write rules/regex for each variration.For that I need to to see in the text like manually so its very hard to find all variations. Here I can't train my program to do automate stuff.